# How do I change stored procedure into Inline SQL statement using VB.Net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an existing stored procedure that need to be used now as inline SQL statement in my VB console application. How do I change it?

Stored Procedure:

```
:Setvar CUSTOMDBNAME "My_DB"

USE [$(CUSTOMDBNAME)]
GO

DECLARE @TranName Varchar(25)
Declare @TranCounter Int
Set  @TranName = 'MyTransaction';
Set  @TranCounter = @@Trancount;

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName;
  BEGIN Try
    UPDATE tbl.FileUpload 
    SET UserCreate= 1
    WHERE ID = 10
  IF @TranCounter=0
      COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName;
  END Try
  BEGIN Catch
     IF @TranCounter = 0     
       Rollback Transaction;
     ELSE
     IF XACT_STATE() <> -1
       Rollback Transaction @TranName;
  END Catch

GO
```

Comment: why do you have to change it to being an inline SQL statement? Do you can still call stored procedures from vb.net or do you need to custom generate part from the application

Comment: It's part of the requirement. This stored procedure is currently being executed manually. Through the console app, this needs to be an inline sql.

Comment: I see no stored procedure. Hint - a stored procedure starts with `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `ALTER PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Still, if you execute it manually you can call a stored procedure from VB. There is no difference in the kind of app is called (it doesnt matter, web, console, etc... same code). But as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, thats not an SP. Check this link for more info about stored procedures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345393.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text of an SQL Server Stored Procedure by querying the `sys.syscomments` view.  From there you can extract the text and do whatever you want with it.

Extensive documentation on how to access data related to different aspects of Stored Procedures is available on MSDN at [Viewing Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190464.aspx).  It explains how to:

- See the definition of the stored procedure. That is, the Transact-SQL statements used to create a stored procedure. This can be useful if you do not have the Transact-SQL script files used to create the stored procedure.
- Get information about a stored procedure such as its schema, when it was created, and its parameters.
- List the objects used by the specified stored procedure, and the procedures that use the specified stored procedure. This information can be used to identify the procedures affected by the changing or removal of an object in the database.

**It seems like using these data sources, you will be able to obtain the data you need, with the remaining work being implementation-specific.**

**In addition**, here is an article demonstrating a use case for querying SPROC text:   http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/03/sql-server-2005-search-stored-procedure-code-search-stored-procedure-text/ .